# Method App\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController::store does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-8

Im trying to import file excel(xlsx) to database using Maatwebsite but got this error.I have function store in my baserepositore. When i add function store to ScheduleController it run and return `schedule.index` but it not import my excel file. Please help me

```
enter code here

 public function importSchedules(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new ScheduleImport, request()->file('file')->store('files'));
    return redirect()->route('schedule.index')->with('success');
}

<div class="form-group">
                    <form method="post" action="/schedule" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="file" name="file">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

Route::post('/schedule', 'ScheduleController@importSchedules');
```

Comment: You need to add a store function to handle the post request

Answer (score 0):

You might have created a resource route as well. Or there must be another route above this route in your web file, so this request might be intercepted by that route. First, make sure about this one. If there is a resource route either you have to add the `store` method on the controller or you could add `except` on the route as shown here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Or, you could change the name of this route as:

```
Route::post('/import-schedules', 'ScheduleController@importSchedules')->name('importSchedules');
```

and on form you have to change to:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('importSchedules')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: My route have Route::resource('schedule', 'ScheduleController')->except(['importSchedules','destroy']);. Also try change the name of route to "/import-schedules" and change acction too but when im open view it return to "Route [importSchedules] not defined.".

Comment: @Cutecat why you adding except `importSchedules`, instead you have to add `except(['store']) because both `store` and `/schedule` have same URL and post method, that's why, it was throwing conflict error.